# Update all records in a typeORM entity

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Anyone knows is there any ways to update all rows/records into one value. eg: Boolean?

My use case is to update status of all notification by changing isRead to true. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to update entities.

1. `EntityManager` and `Repository` offer an `update(criteria, partialUpdate)` method.

```
await notificationRepository.update({}, { isRead: true });
// executes UPDATE notification SET isRead = true
```

This would also allow you specify a criteria what records should be updated, e.g.

```
await notificationRepository.update({ userId: 123} , { isRead: true });
// executes UPDATE notification SET isRead = true WHERE userId = 123
```

Find documentation for `update()` [here](https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api).

2. Using [migrations](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md)

If you want to set isRead to true for all records because you added this field and all existing notifications should be marked as read, this could be done with a migration. A migration will be executed only one time.

This is how the migration could look like:

```
export class SetIsReadTrue1626875696087 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'SetIsReadTrue1626875696087';

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query('UPDATE `notification` SET `isRead` = true');
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query('UPDATE `notification` SET `isRead` = false');
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is quite a comprehensive answer. Let me try them out. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @hweiu321 Hope it worked for you? Please don't forget to accept the answer, if it answers your question.